# Android Studio crash on Fedora

Tags: android, android-studio

I've installed Android Studio on Fedora, copying it on `/opt/Android studio/`, but every time I open it through `/opt/Android studio/bin/studio.sh`, after few clicks it crashes and it returns

```
(java:4075): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_threads_set_lock_functions: assertion 'gdk_threads_lock == NULL && gdk_threads_unlock == NULL' failed
Attempt to unlock mutex that was not locked
./studio.sh: line 188:  4075 Aborted                 (core dumped) LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$IDE_BIN_HOME:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" "$JDK/bin/java" $AGENT "-Xbootclasspath/a:$IDE_HOME/lib/boot.jar" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" $VM_OPTIONS "-Djb.vmOptionsFile=$VM_OPTIONS_FILES_USED" "-XX:ErrorFile=$HOME/java_error_in_STUDIO_%p.log" -Djb.restart.code=88 -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio1.2 $IDE_PROPERTIES_PROPERTY $IDE_JVM_ARGS $REQUIRED_JVM_ARGS $MAIN_CLASS_NAME "$@"
```

and I don't know why.

Sorry for my bad English but I'm not native

Comment: Did you set the correct permissions? Try to unpack and run Android Studio in your home directory instead.

Comment: Hi, I've already tried it but without success:(
Thank you, anyway

Comment: Looks like the issue is related to the underlying Java process. Very similar error happens to my IntelliJ. I run on Fedora 22, openjdk-1.8.0.51-4.b16.
Please post here the solution when you find that.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same issue but fixed it after running the following install:

```
dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64
```

Comment: No, they write: "_fixed_ it after running the following". It's not a new question.

Comment: you've save my day